# Migrating magento to new server causes incomplete templates

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I'm working locally on a Magento install, when I try to upload the sources to the production server it starts happening something very frustrating: the homepage output is not complete, I only see a section of the page instead of seeing the whole page.

I zipped the local copy and transferred using *scp* so I don't think it can be some missing file, the only thing I updated was the *media* directory, but from what I know it has to do with media assets, not with templates... I uploaded the source several times, and nothing...

Also the DB is the same copy, so it cannot be an issue.
The output HTML is different (and for instance it's also missing the closing body and html tags.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you have a fatal error which is causing the page to exit, hence the lack of tags. I assume you are not getting any errors displayed? Is it possible to enable error messages displaying?

Comment: Double-check the source of the page and make sure it's pointing to the correct directories. Use firebug's network panel to check for 404s as well.

Comment: @MattHumphrey yeah, I've enabled php errors, but I can't still see an error message... I've also enabled errors/local.xml to get magento errors.... do I need to do something else to see errors?

Comment: @aynber I zipped and uploaded the very same directory it's working on the staging server, Firebug is not reporting any 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip

http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Since the only difference is the server you need to make sure it has all those pre-requisites checked.

Comment: Yeah!! You really made my day... The sysadmin forgot to install php-gd, and one of the extensions was simply not working instead of printing an exception... I'll make a patch for the extension, and tomorrow I'll plan a revenge for the sysadmin... something that will keep him busy the whole day, like this issue did with me :-)

Comment: ...now if only you could help me wit how to get the shipping cost of an order from my module! Ahh... Nevermind.